# cant make pdf invoice when in production mode

Tags: pdf, magento-2.1.3, fatal-error, create-invoice

When in development mode I can create **pdf** invoices just fine but when in **production mode** I get an **error**.

Under **sales > Invoices** I'm clicking the "**Print**" button to get a pdf of a invoice (see link)

[image: pdf invoice]

It now says:
There has been an error processing your request

> Warning: strspn() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/dragoni5/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Pdf/StringParser.php on line 162

I'd really appreciate any feedback on this.

Comment: did you used any custom module for your sales?